# Android Listview changes icon when scrolled

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a `ListView` on my Android App. Each row has a text and an image. When the user clicks a row, the row's image is changed (this works fine). The problem is, when the user scrolls the `ListView`, at the moment the row crosses the top part of the `ListView` (when you stop seeing that row), the image changes back to the default one automatically. How can I prevent this? If the user clicks the row and the image is changed, I need that new image to stay there (since the new image is the indicator for the user that he already clicked the row).

Thank you for your help!
Here's my code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent i;
            ImageView imageView;

            switch (position){
                case 0:

                    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_alimentacion);

                    if (frutas.equals("NO")){
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox);

                        frutas = "SI";
                    }else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_inactivo);
                        frutas = "NO";
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:

                    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_alimentacion);
                    if (verdura.equals("NO")){
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox);
                        verdura = "SI";
                    }else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_inactivo);
                        verdura = "NO";
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:

                    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_alimentacion);

                    if (carne.equals("NO")){
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox);
                        carne = "SI";
                    }else {
                        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkbox_inactivo);
                        carne = "NO";
                    }

                    break;

            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Post your adapter code too

Comment: I think there must be some mistakes in adapter getView().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well firstly, this is an interesting question.

The images are being replaced because when the list-item view exits the screen it is destroyed, and whenever it reappears it is newly created again. Entirely from scratch. A drawback of listview. A better way to do is to use a [RecyclerView](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-tutorial/). It will create objects for each row using a ViewHolder and later instead of creating everything from scratch, it refers the already created ViewHolder objects.

However, the user selection for a row still needs to be handled all by ourselves here. I would suggest as follows.

Create a global boolean array of same length as your listview.

```
boolean[] selected=new boolean[listViewLength];
```

Now, inside `onItemClickListener()`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       //change value of boolean to true, to depict as selected
       selected[position]=true;       //default value of boolean is false.

       //update the image
       imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_alimentacion);
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkedDrawable);
    }
});
```

And finally in your `getView()` check for the selection which will look something like this,

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    //Initialize the item-view
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listItemLayout,null,false);

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.check_alimentacion);

    if(selected[position]){
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkedDrawable);
    }
    else{
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultDrawable);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! @DarshanMiskin One more thing.. How do I use the Boolean array in the "getView()" method? How do I create it as a global variable so that I can enter the values in the activity and use those values in the adapter??

Comment: are your adapter and activity in different java files? If so, move the adapter class to the java file of the activity having the listview. If not, then just declare the boolean array at class level of activity.

Comment: and don't forget to accept the answer when it does your job. :)

Answer (score 0):

Views inside listview are recycled.
You should store each view's state in some kind of array;

For example in `List<Integer> itemsImageRes`, where `itemsImageRes.get(i)` will be cached imageResId of listView element at position `i`

And you should set this image resource to imageView on your adapters `getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

And good idea is to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.drawableid);`